Maximum Number of Threads for Parallel Computing in R: Is it 128?
I am using R for parallel computing on a machine with the following specs:

2 x AMD EPYC 7K62 CPUs
48 cores and 96 threads per CPU
Total: 96 cores and 192 threads

I am trying to utilize all available threads using the following code:
no_cores <- detectCores()  # 192
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores, outfile = '')
`
However, I encounter the following error:

Error in file(con, "w") : all 128 connections are in use

When I reduce the ‘no_cores’ value to around 120, the code executes without any errors. This leads me to question whether there is a limit on the number of parallel threads that can be utilized on the Windows 10 platform.
Is it true that the maximum number of threads for parallel computing in R on Windows is around 128? If so, is there any way to fully utilize my CPU resources?

https://github.com/tobigithub/R-parallel/wiki/R-parallel-Errors#snow-and-dosnow---all-connections-are-in-use <- it is a limitation, the way to overcome it involves recompiling R

Well, I'll try to accept that I can only use less than 128 threads!@teapot418

3 connections will be used up by standard in/out/error ; leaving 125 connections per R session. However I dont think you are limited to how many independent R sessions you can run. so you can open up R/Rstudio twice, and if you can chunk the workload you could presumably use as many as 250 connections ; or given your hardware limits. 192 total.   but perhaps I'm wrong on this point.

R source code of connections.c states:

As from R 4.4.0 the default limit remains 128, but can be overriden
by the startup option --max-connections.  This does not allow it to
be set below 128 but has a limit of 4096 (see CommandLineArgs.c).
The upper limit is conservative, but as creating a new connection
uses a linear search in the connections table, some limit is
needed. (When checked the table used 488 bytes per connection.)

So start R with the --max-connections option to set the desired limit up to 4096, e.g.
R --max-connections=192

Note, that special connections stdin, stdout, and stderr are included, see respective loop line 181 starts at i = 3.
Also note, that you might need to increase your file descriptor values accordingly. On Unix-alikes, e.g.
ulimit -n 4096

